# Need help identifying CSST manufacturer

Tags: hvac, csst, identify-a-tool

Can anyone tell me who is the manufacturer of this CSST (and related fixture)?

[image: CSST]
[image]

Comment: You might try wiping the dust off off and taking new pictures **specifically going for a complete set of the text,** given your question.

Comment: Any reason for wanting to know?  Imagine any make of 1/2 inch(any size) pipe has the same specs.

Comment: @crip659  Wrong!  The CSST fittings are not necessarily interchangeable across brands.  CSST fittings and tubing must, generally, be matching set by manufacturer.   The main difference being the pitch of the corrugation.

Comment: @codechimp  Thank you for that information.

Answer (score 2):

If the conversation at [InterNACHI](https://forum.nachi.org/t/identify-the-logo/207908) is correct, then your CSST is Titeflex brand.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Titeflex product. That funny "Tg" looking trademark is an earlier Titeflex logo.  They make Gastite.